# Python splitting time string of "4d12h33m59s" format into pieces

Tags: python, string, time, split

I was wondering if anyone could help to come up with an elegant solution how to split a time string received from router's API of format `"4d12h33m59s"` into pieces.

The problem is that string could be dynamical size. For example, it can be `"4d12h33m59s"` or `"12h33m59s"` or `"12y14w4d12h33m59s"` or `"12m23s"`, `"33s"`.

Is there any elegant way to have split the string and get a list like:

```
received_string = "12y14w4d12h33m59s"
time_list = convert_string(received_string)

print(time_list) 
["12y","14w","4d","12h","33m","59s"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto):

```
import re

time_list = re.findall('\d+[a-z]', received_string)
```

The [`re.findall()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) produces a list of all matches of a given pattern in the input string. Here the pattern looks for 1 or more digits, followed by one lower-case ASCII letter.

You could make it more picky about what letters are allowed by using `[ywdhms]`, but if your input is reasonably well-formed I'd not worry about that.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> received_string = "12y14w4d12h33m59s"
>>> re.findall('\d+[a-z]', received_string)
['12y', '14w', '4d', '12h', '33m', '59s']
```

You may want to further split out the digits and letters, however, to make it easier to then transform the information into an easier to work with format like a `datetime.timedelta()` object, perhaps into a dictionary:

```
{type_: int(count) for count, type_ in re.findall('(\d+)([a-z])', received_string)}
```

The added `(..)` groupings alter the `re.findall()` output to produce a tuple for each match, containing the separate group values (so `('12', 'y')`, `('14', 'w')`, etc.).

This produces

```
{'y': 12, 'w': 14, 'd': 4, 'h': 12, 'm': 33, 's': 59}
```

for your input.

Comment: Waaaaaat? Man, I did not expect to get a perfect answer so quick! Thank you, you are my hero! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Martijn's answer is excellent as usual. I just thought I'd expand a touch on a way to use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) in this conversion:

```
import datetime, re, operator, functools
times = {'s': datetime.timedelta(seconds=1),
         'm': datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
         'h': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
         'd': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
         'w': datetime.timedelta(weeks=1),
         'y': datetime.timedelta(days=365)}
fieldre = re.compile(r'(\d+)([{}])'.format(''.join(times.keys())))

samplevalue = "12y14w4d12h33m59s"

duration = functools.reduce(operator.add, 
     (times[unit]*int(value) for (value,unit) in 
      fieldre.findall(samplevalue)))

remains = fieldre.subn("", samplevalue)
if remains:
    raise ValueError("Unexpected time fields in {!r}: {!r}".format(
        samplevalue, remains))
```

Admittedly, that last is a bit of a mess. Note that the year unit is a rough approximation (365 days). I used `dict.keys` to extract those units and permit them in the regular expression, parenthesis in the regular expression to produce value and unit as a pair, and `functools.reduce(operator.add, iterable)` as a substitute for `sum` because the latter didn't work on `timedelta`. In the end we have a single timedelta we can read normalized times from with e.g. `duration.total_seconds()`.

Possibly more usefully I added a way to detect if we've left something out using `subn`. Wrong data could be more harmful than detecting invalid conversions.